# NameError: name '*' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

Why this line `add(root, sum, 0)` gets `NameError: name 'add' is not defined` error?

```
class Solution:
    def rob(root: TreeNode) -> int:
        sum = [0, 0]
        add(root, sum, 0)
        if sum[0] < sum[1]:
            return sum[1]
        else:
            return sum[0]

    def add(node: TreeNode, sum: List[int], index: int):
        if not node:
            return
        sum[index] += node.val
        index += 1
        if index >= len(sum):
            index = 0;
        add(node.left, sum, index)
        add(node.right, sum, index)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they are class functions, make use of `self`

Define like this:
`def add(self, node: TreeNode, sum: List[int], index: int):`

and use it

`self.add(node.left, sum, index)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
class Solution:
    def rob(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        sum = [0, 0]
        self.add(root, sum, 0)
        if sum[0] < sum[1]:
             return sum[1]
        else:
             return sum[0]

    def add(self, node: TreeNode, sum: List[int], index: int):
        if not node:
            return
        sum[index] += node.val
        index += 1
        if index >= len(sum):
            index = 0;
        self.add(node.left, sum, index)
        self.add(node.right, sum, index)
```